# How to fade in a text after page loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get a div container with some text to fade in after the page loaded, but I fail. I was using the ng-animate directive like this:

```
<div class="motd" style="text-align: center;" ng-init="quote = getQuote();">
    <div class="slide-fade" ng-class="animation">
        <span class="quote"><i>{{quote.content}}</i></span><br><br>
        <span class="author">{{quote.author}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which obviously does not work, due to the fact that the animation does not get triggered by a click or something like that.

So how do I tell the browser that after the page loaded, it should fade in my text?

I hope you can help me!

**Edit:** At the date where I asked, I did not know that animations will also trigger when the page has loaded. I always thought there have to be some "user interaction" like a click or something to trigger them.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using bootstrap, you can do this:

```
<html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
<head>...</head>
<body ng-init="ngLoaded = true" class="fade" ng-class="{ in: ngLoaded }">
  <div>Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It may also work do to it this way as well:

```
<body
  ng-app="myApp"
  ng-strict-di
  ng-init="ngLoaded = true"
  class="fade"
  ng-class="{ in: ngLoaded }">
<div> Content </div>
</body>
```

The `fade` class has 0 opacity and the `in` class applies the transition. `ngLoaded` will become true (in the $rootScope, I believe) as soon as angular has loaded due to `ng-init="ngLoaded = true"`.

I use this so that the page doesn't blip with bits of angular brackets and such while the page loads.

Comment: This is a great answer, if you are waiting on a variable to load within the Content div, remove `ng-init="ngLoaded = true"` and change ng-class to `ng-class="{ in: yourVariableHere }"`

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem. 
 You just want to have animation when the element appears( you can think about it that way right? ).
Basicaly what I would do.
I would use then animate.css 
http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/
and I would just add:

```
 class="animated fadeIn"
```

Or plain css with this animation.
What I like to do is to use delay

```
.delayedx1{
    animation-delay: 0.2s !important;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s !important;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0.2s !important;
    -o-animation-delay: 0.2s !important;
    -webkit-transition-delay:0.2s;
    transition-delay:0.2s;
}
```

x2 x3 x4 or in ng repeat delay directly in "style" based on $index.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use a flag (like `$scope.fade = false;`) to indicate that the page has loaded. Then, on your element, you'd use an `ng-class` with a conditional e.g.

```
class="animation" ng-class="{'fade-in': fade }"
```

The actual fade would be handled by CSS.

```
.animation { opacity:0; transition:all 200ms ease-in-out; }

.animation.fade-in { opacity:1; }
```

In your case, the `fade-in` condition could be as simple as `ng-class="{'fade-in': quote }"` since any truthy value you cause the class to get applied.

Here's a working plunker for you to play around with: http://plnkr.co/edit/ncqEB3PafIWbwv0UH1QG?p=preview

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer. I think I didn't make up myself clear :P I don't want the fade in triggered by a click or something like that. I want the execution right after the page loaded, automatically.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you set a flag as a result of a button click or as a result of a server response in `getQuote()`. As I said, you can use `ng-class="{'fade-in': quote }"` and once that variable is set to some value on your scope, the class will be applied.